# Парсинг Веб страницы на Python

Tags: python, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем добрый день. Как проводите майские праздники? Возник вопрос по поводу парсинга на Python, подскажите как решить. Посмотрите фото. Мне нужно спарсить текст. Есть див, который отвечает за блок:

```
<div class="ecoCalContent">
```

Но мне нужны не все данные, а только текст (самый правый столбец).
Но как мне взять этот текст? Там нет ни span, ни h1. Написано #text. 
Вот мой код, но он не работает:

```
text = soup.find('div', data='Details').find_all('div', class_="tblContent5")
```

На фотографии можно заметить, что класс у этого текста: tblContent5

```
<div data-th="Details" data-group="calData" class="tblContent5">
```

**Как мне взять этот текст?**
 Loews Corp. (L) will host a conference call at 11:00 AM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q4 19 earnings results.

To access the live webcast, log on to www.loews.com

To listen to... .

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Фото? Пожалуйста, вставьте его в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Извините, совсем забыл,  спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищете по всему документу `<div>` с `data='Details'`. Но в документе нет такого `<div>` (есть только с `data-th="Details"`).

Найдите `<div>` любым удобным Вам способом и получите текст через атрибут `text`.

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('index.html', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')

text = soup.find('div', {'class': 'ecoCalContent'}).find('div', {'class': 'tblContent5'}).text
print(text)
```

***stdout:***

```html
Some text
```

***index.html:***

```html
<div class="ecoCalContent">
  <div data-th="Details" class="tblContent5">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скрипт работает, спасибо